# How to create a table with days column in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I create one attendance management system right now. I stuck in someplace like I need to display all employee attendance report at a single table in that table I need to display name, days, and total hour of the month columns. I try some ways to achieve to create the day's column but I am failed to find a proper way to achieve this table so please help me how can I create this table.

i want the final output like this :-

[image]

Comment: share some code so we know what u have done.

Comment: Each column would have to include an object made up of a `Header` and `accessor` assuming you do not need any searching or filtering. The entire row of columns would be an array of these objects.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial i try this thing https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-hooks-s4xtm?file=/src/App.js:523-526